# Publish/subscribe listen for all topic #

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I am using Apache ActiveMQ  as a Brocker and Sensor devices continously publish data to it.
  I want to write a subsriber #  whih collect all data that broker listens.
Whther a client implemation can really scale for this kind of opeartion. what are the things to be considerd while  making such client set up(  subscriber)

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a separate client subscribed to # will work will very much depend on the throughput/load levels involved and how well that client is written.

Some brokers (e.g. HiveMQ) have plugins that will do DB persistence directly at the broker level which for very high throughput situations may be better.